# contenteditable=false in contenteditable=true

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, contenteditable

**Problem:**

I have observed an undesirable behaviour in Chrome and Opera that occurs when one joins two p
tags by deleting the separation between them. Chrome and Opera delete contenteditable=false element(widget) and text after.

**Example:**

[example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pCXmA/1/)

html:

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="editor">
<p>This is the first paragraph.</p>
<p>&larr;Place your cursor here and press backspace. <span class="widget" contenteditable="false">widget</span> Text after widget</p> 
</div>
```

css:

```
.widget{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: gray;
}

.editor{
    font: 20px Trebuchet MS
}
```

**Question:**

Why? How fix it?

Comment: You mean Opera with Blink engine? I cannot cofirm in Opera 12.

Comment: Is there a solution for this already?

Comment: This issue seems to have been resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reported this bug long time ago for [Blink](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=306970) and [Webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=122748). It's kind of critical and there's no workaround. Webkit team tried to fix it, but as far as I can see, they introduced new bug ;|.

PS. Yes, this answer does not propose any fix, but the only fix is overriding <kbd>delete</kbd> and <kbd>backspace</kbd> keys behaviour.