# non editable div inside editable div

Tags: html, events, browser

when deleting line which contains a non editable div inside editable div , non editable div is deleted automatically.

to reproduce :

1. press enter inside "aa" text
2. press backspace

the result:  all red text is deleted automatically.

here is the simple  html code :

```
<div contenteditable="true" >
    <div style="display:inline">
        aa
    </div>
    <div contenteditable="false" style="background-color:red ;display:inline"">
        bb
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello! Where is the question?

Comment: why the non editable div is deleted automatically

Comment: refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21733887/9668010,there is a bug in Webkit for delete key.